# Cannot instantiate subclass due to compile-time exception

Tags: java, file, subclass

I'm new to java and am running into the error

> An enclosing instance that contains ... is required

when creating a new object from a subclass defined in the same source file as its parent, but not when the subclass has its own source file, and I'd like to understand why.

The main file:

```
package tessty
public class Tessty {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person me = new Person();
        me.addtoitems();
    }
}
```

Another source file for the "Person" class:

```
package tessty;
import tessty.Item.*; // I included this import as per NetBeans' suggestions

public class Person {

    Item[] items;

    public Person() {
        items = new Item[3];
    }

    public void addtoitems() {
        items[0] = new Apple(); // Compile error thrown here
        items[1] = new Shoe(); // and here
        items[2] = new Hat(); // but not here
    }
}
```

The "Item" class source file with two sub-classes defined in the same file:

```
package tessty;

public class Item {

    int weight;

    public class Apple extends Item {
        public Apple() {
            weight = 2;
        }
    }

    public class Shoe extends Item {
        public Shoe() {
            weight = 3;
        }
    }

}
```

And finally, another child of Item, but defined in its own source file:

```
package tessty;

public class Hat extends Item {

    public Hat() {
        weight = 1;        
    }

}
```

I'd really like to be able to define sub-classes in the same file as the parent class for organizational purposes (the application I'm working on will have many "small" sub-classes). Could someone please explain why I'm getting this error only for the sub-classes that are in the same source file as their parents? Is it related to the fact I have to use an import for the sub-classes in the same file as their parent and not for the sub-class with its own file?

Comment: `Apple` and `Shoe` need to be declared `static` to work the way you are trying.

Comment: Thanks all, using the static modifier does indeed remove the error. I didn't realize defining a subclass in the same source file makes it an "inner" class, so I'm going to go read up on those.

Comment: I took the liberty of re-titling your question to better reflect your question and remove any suggestion this was opinion-based, and also to remove the tag from the title (future tip: don't put tags in titles).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make your subclasses [*static member classes*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) for this to work. As it is they are [*inner classes*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html), but there is no point in using those in your case. You could also make `Item` `abstract` as you don't intend to create any instance of it.

If you were to create non-nested classes in a single file, only one can be `public` (as [per the JLS 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.6) at the bottom of section 7.6). Therefore if you want multiple public non-nested subclasses, they must all be in separate files.

```
package tessty;

public abstract class Item {

    int weight;

    public static class Apple extends Item {
        public Apple() {
            weight = 2;
        }
    }

    public static class Shoe extends Item {
        public Shoe() {
            weight = 3;
        }
    }

}
```

In summary, classes are:

- *top level* if they are not enclosed in any other class
- *nested* if they are enclosed in another class (*nested* can mean *static* or not, and declared as a *member*, *local* or *anonymous* class)

Within the *nested* set they are:

- *member* if they are declared immediately within the class definition block
- [*local*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html) if they are declared inside a method
- [*anonymous*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) if they are declared with an instance creation expression

And *nested* classes are either:

- *static member* if they are static (therefore they must only be *member*)
- [*inner*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html) if they are not static (these can be *member*, *local* or *anonymous*)

*Inner classes* receive an implicit reference to the instance of the parent that created it. *Static member* classes have no implicit knowledge of any parent instance.

Answer (score 5):

First, your `Testty` class doesn't compile. You've missed a `;` after the package statement:

```
package tessty;
```

Then, you can define super and subclass in one source file, but one of them has to be `public` and you need the `package` statement just once (because it's shared for both of the classes). For example:

```
package something;

public class SuperClass {

}

class SubClass extends SuperClass {

}
```

The source-file they will be stored, will have to be named `SuperClass.java`.

Alternatively, you can make the sub-class(es) nested and `static`, as answered by @AndyBrown.

Comment: There's one case you missed, when you declare SubClass `public static`

Comment: @ControlAltDel I believe that would be when you put `SubClass` inside of `SuperClass`, right?

Comment: No, in the snippet I've provided, if `SubClass` is `static` (no matter `public` or not), it doesn't compile.

Comment: Yes, the static modifier could make sense if SubClass were defined as an inner class relative to SuperClass, but since that is not the case here, it's good. Even for an inner class, there is no requirement for it to be declared as static, however.